# Silverlight 4 Out Of Browser and Upgrade

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Can someone explain how the Silverlight 4 OOB upgrades happen? Is it click one? Would the OOB shell automatically download the latest xap from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to code up the check for and download upgrades from within your application.  You do this using [`Application.CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.checkanddownloadupdateasync(VS.96).aspx).

See also [Checking for Application Updates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721(v=VS.96).aspx#checking_for_application_updates)